# Is there a way to change the scale of spectogram axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have and audio file, of which I plot the Spectrogram  in MATLAB using :

```
M = 2048;
spectrogram(data,hanning(M),M/2,0:20:10000,fs,'yaxis');
```

the result looks fine  : 
[image: spectrogram]

the Time axis is scaled from `0 tell 20`, my question is there a way to make it look  `0 tell 200` a keep the plot as it is ?

Comment: Yes you can, but it may not make sense. What is the size of `data` (how many points?) and what is the sampling frequency of your signal `fs` ?

Comment: @hoki the length of the file is : 201600 with fs of 96000

Comment: Are you sure about that ? that would make only `201600/96000=2.1 seconds` worth of data. Not 21 as in your graph.

Comment: sorry I forgot one 0 , it's 2016000

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but that's a really cool spectrogram.

Comment: @Engine Is this the spectrogram of a room impulse response? Image source method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to make the x-axis "look like" it goes from 0 to 200, you can redefine the `XTickLabels`.

Here is the code:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:20);           % Place Ticks at 0, 1, 2 ... 20
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 0:10:200);   % Mark them as 0, 10, 20 ... 200
```

It won't change anything to the plot itself, only the x-axis display.

Best,

Answer (score 2):

You should simply do somthing like:

```
xlim([0 200])
```

It will resize the x-axis

Answer (score 0):

Given the size of your input data and the sample rate, there must only be a bit over 20 seconds worth of samples. If the array is meant to represent 200 seconds then you must have your sample rate specified wrong - it should be about 10 times slower. Otherwise you'll need more input data. If there's only 20 seconds of data to plot then there is no way it is going to plot 200 seconds worth.

I think `xlim([0 200])` will set the axis to 0 to 200, but the data will only be in the first 20 seconds - the rest of the plot will be blank.

Comment: thanks for your answer , well actually, this are 0 tell 200 rpm in 20 sec ,